# ubuntu 12.04.LTS alongside windows 8 boot menu not shown

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I bought Acer Aspire V5 Laptop with Windows 8 Pre installed, upgraded to Windows 8.1 and I have two partitions C and E.

I have used disk management to shrink E to form an unallocated space and Restarted the Laptop twice.

I went to UEFI and disabled secure boot. After that I inserted Bootable Ubuntu 12.04 LTS DVD and  it has not detected my Windows 8.

I chose the "something else" option and installed Ubuntu in the unallocated space. Now, whenever I start the Laptop, boot menu is not shown but ubuntu is loaded straight away instead.

I tried with Boot Repair in ubuntu, but it showed Repair failed with URL http://paste.ubuntu.com/6732706/.

Also when i click update manager in ubuntu 12.04 LTS...it has listed three updates namely:

1)Interact with EFI Boot Manager

2)Grub Version 2(EFI-AMD 64 binaries)

3)Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX, where i can check mark only 3rd option.

now when i click "install updates", its asking me into insert "Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Slander DVD". Even after inserting that..no use..Technically i could not understand why its asking fro 13.10 DVD when i use 12.04 LTS..

Answer (score 1):

From the boot repair log it was clearly shown that you had installed grub legacy 0.97 on the MBR of `/dev/sda` which was an old version of grub.Try to update your grub from grub legacy 0.97 to grub2.

[*Upgrading to Grub 2 From Grub 0.97*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Upgrading#Upgrading_to_GRUB_2_From_GRUB_0.97).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot..i have done it, but in boot menu i could  not see windows 8, but i can see "System Setup" option.